# rails date_select correspond to text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date

Using date_select I am trying to take the selected value, get the corresponding month number and set a text_field to that selected value.

```
<%= form_for @goal, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal goal' } do |f| %>
  <%= date_select :month_name, :use_month_names, :discard_year => 'true', :discard_day => 'true'  %>
  <%= f.text_field :month_num, :value => #access above selected value and parse to number %>
<% end %>
```

I would assume there is a more elegant way.

How can achieve this without polluting this view?

Comment: Do you want the value in the text field after a form submission? If no, you will need javascript to map the value.

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking about that.. But I do want the value afterwards.

Comment: Can you post the full form_for or form_tag?

Comment: <%= form_for @goal, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal goal' }  do |f| %>

Comment: After you submit the form, does the value for @goal get updated with an attribute `:month_num`?

Comment: well.. in my current code, yes. basically the form needs to show the months of the year and when submitted needs to submit the month number as opposed to the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71355/discussion-between-eabraham-and-captainrad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better option is to drop the `text_field` and extract the month in the controller.